# Can't figure out how people are registering on my site

Tags: user-registration, notifications

I get email daily from wordpress@domain.com when someone registers on my site but I've shut down all ability to register, at least as far as I know.  It's a really simple site so it's not like I have a vast number of pages where another registration page could be hiding.  Any ideas on why this would be happening and how I can find the source?

Comment: First of all check what happen if you enter on your browser http://domain.com/wp-login.php?action=register to be sure the registration is off.

Answer (score 0):

To stop unwanted registration on your WordPress site, go to admin panel, go to settings>general, then untick Membership (any one can register option).

Comment: Thanks, Nanda.  That's good to know but I found how it was happening. I had added a 'subscribe' link in a place I had not seen before.